# Using a %username% in a variable not working

Tags: batch-file, path

I have an batch "Shell" where it loads files that contain a line of code then executes the line. But I am having trouble with this line of code: `dir C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata` It looks for %username% instead of my username. I found this out when I changed it to my username.

**PROGRAM:**

`dir C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata`

`goto wellosnocls`

`GOWELL` (Which is the program maker command to end the code)

**THE PROGRAM OPENER:**

`:po`

`set lines=0`

`echo ----------------%command%------------------`

`:porep`

`set /a lines=%lines% + 1`

`set /p "code="<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%\%command%-%lines%".wellcode`

`%code%`

`goto porep`

**THE WHOLE SHELL:**

```
@set /p build=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\WellOS\Build".txt
@title WellOS V.%build%
goto boot
:register
cls
echo You are registering...
echo If this is an error press CTRL + C NOW...
pause
cls
set /p user= Enter your username: 
set /p passwordreg= Enter your password: 
mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%"
mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%\Documents"
echo %passwordreg% >"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%\password".txt
echo 2 >"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\OSfiles\bootset".txt
echo Your done.
pause
goto welloslog
:booterror
echo Sorry the boot file has an error. Check the user manual for BOOT$
pause
:boot
set /p boot=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\OSfiles\bootset".txt
if %boot% == 1 goto register
if %boot% == 2 goto welloslog
goto booterror
cls
:ERROR
cls
echo ----------ERROR-------------------
echo %error%
pause
goto %back%
:welloslog
cls
echo Welcome to WellOS2!
echo ----------------LOGIN-------------
set /p user= Username: 
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%" goto pass
set error= Sorry that account doesn't exist.
set back=welloslog
welloslogerror
:pass
set /p password=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%\password".txt
set /p passwordlog= Password: 
if /i %passwordlog% == %password% goto wellos
set error= Sorry! wrong password.
set back= welloslog
goto error
:wellos
cls
:wellosnocls
echo --------------MAIN---------------
echo type help.sys for help
set /p command= #: 
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%" goto po
set error= Unreconized program/command.
set back=wellos
goto error
:po
set lines=0
echo --------------%command%---------------
:porep
set /a lines=%lines% + 1
set /p "code="<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%\%command%-%lines%".wellcode
%code%
goto porep
```

Comment: Without seeing the entire code ([edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33928470/edit) to include it, do **not** add it in a comment), this is just a guess, but you generally only see that behavior when the variable doesn't exist. Since `%username%` is an environment variable, it should always exist, unless you have a `set username=` statement somewhere in your code.

Comment: @somethingdark The os's code or the programs code?

Comment: Whichever contains the line of code that's giving you trouble. (Also, the more pedantic of us will point out that you're not making an operating system, you're making a shell.)

Comment: I suggest using `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata"`. Why using quotes? A user name (account name) can contain a space character or other characters requiring double quotes. Why using environment variable __USERPROFILE__? Then it works also if the profiles directory of the user accounts is not on drive C: for all or just some accounts and also for Windows 2000/XP and any later Windows independent on language of OS.

Comment: @SomethingDark It's updated.

Comment: @SomethingDark Remember, It is being loaded then executed. with the `set /p blah=<C:\Blah` command. Then `%blah%` (the variable) is executed.

Comment: True, but `%username%` should always exist by default, since it's a Windows system variable. You may want to include a line that is nothing but the command `set` just to see what variables exist at the time of execution.

Comment: @SomethingDark I checked it exists at the time of the execution. I even got rid of the echo off, and checked that way. It says dir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata"

Comment: If the code in the shell is inside of parentheses, you may need to use `!username!` instead. (Although admittedly, I'm guessing at this point since you haven't shown your other code.)

Comment: @SomethingDark The whole code is in there now.

Comment: @SomethingDark Again, The problem is not that the path is wrong, But as when it is executed in a variable it has an error.

Comment: @SomethingDark What do you mean inside of parentheses?

Comment: I mean somewhere between a `(` and a `)`, but that doesn't seem to be applicable here. I'm not going to be in front of a computer for another 15+ hours (I'm posting from my phone right now), but at this point, all I can recommend trying is putting `call` in front of `%code%` in `:porep`. After that, I'm out of ideas until I get home.

Comment: @SomethingDark It worked! Thanks!

Comment: @SomethingDark There is one problem... The batch label. When it is called it is the same as saying goto to it.

Comment: Was reading this thread and noticed you have 2 misspelled words. 1) `echo Your done.` should be `echo You are done.` or `You’re done.`  2) `Unreconized` should be `Unrecognized`.

Comment: @Kory Gill How exactly are you helping... That is the program, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you run code using `set /p` and redirected input `<`, you will only execute a single line of the input file.  In your example "PROGRAM" above, only the `dir` command will run, the other 2 statements never will.

If you want the `dir C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata` to run and not give the error "The system cannot find the path specified." then change it to `cmd /c dir C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata`.  As mentioned in the comments, using `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `c:\users\%username%` will make your code more robust.